# How to Rewind Video Player in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video-player

I am attempting to rewind a VideoPlayer in Unity, also I am using the new VideoPlayer API and an mp4. I have tried setting the playback speed to a negative number, but it pauses.
My current solution is

**In my rewind button script:**

```
void Update ()
{

    if (rewind == true) {
        VideoController.Backward2Seconds();

    }

}
```

**In my VideoController Script**

```
public void Backward2Seconds() {
    if (!IsPlaying) return;
        videoPlayer.time = videoPlayer.time - 2;
}
```

Is there a better way? Because this is laggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I am afraid that your first try was the best one, and that it is just your platform that doesn't support it. It could work on other devices. According to the [VideoPlayer doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-playbackSpeed.html):

> Support for negative values is platform dependent

Since it seems that this solution doesn't work on your device, your workaround might be improved by taking in account the time that passed between each frame. Try the following:

**In you RewindButton script**

```
void Update ()
{
    if (rewind == true) {
        VideoController.Backward(Time.deltaTime);
    } 
}
```

**In your VideoController Script**

```
public float Speed;

public void Backward(float deltaTime) 
{
    if (!IsPlaying) return;
        videoPlayer.time = videoPlayer.time - deltaTime*Speed;
}
```

This should allow you to control the speed of the rewind while having a more fluid effect

Comment: I tried it out, and it seems to have indeed made the playback smoother. Not by much, but improvement indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is often confusion about the term "rewind", I assume a few people will come here looking into how to replay a video from the beginning.

Here's how I do it. I used this code quite a few times (tested on Android and iOS). You can call `PlayCurrentVideoClip` to replay the current videoClip.

```
    public void PlayCurrentVideoClip()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(videoPlayer.clip);
        PlayVideoClip(videoPlayer.clip);
    }

    public void PlayVideoClip(VideoClip _vc) {
        StartCoroutine(PlayVideoClipCoroutine(_vc));
    }

    IEnumerator PlayVideoClipCoroutine(VideoClip _vc) {
        videoPlayerUI?.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); // safely wait 1 frame for the UI to be active
        SetVideoClip(_vc);
        videoPlayer.enabled = true;
        videoPlayer.frame = 0;
        videoPlayer.Play();
        videoPlayer.EnableAudioTrack(0, true);
        OnPlay.Invoke();
    }
```

In my example the final code is in a coroutine because I had to enable some UI first. If you don't have to do that you should be fine with a normal method (non coroutine).

The only downside is that you might see a bit of a glitch where the video panel disappears for a split second. Can be annoying but not the end of the world.