# How to reversely play a video in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video, ffmpeg, virtual-reality

I am implementing a VR 360 video viewer in Unity and need to implement a "play in reverse" function. Some approaches I tried (and obviously failed):

1. Set the playbackSpeed field of the VideoPlayer in a negative number.

   - Result: Video pauses
2. Reversing the video frame by frame using the method suggested here: [How to Rewind Video Player in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910927/how-to-rewind-video-player-in-unity)

   - Result: Super laggy playback
3. Instead of using the default VideoPlayer, use Vive Media Player (which builds on top of ffmpeg) (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/vive-media-decoder-63938). Reverse the video frame by frame and force the renderer to render the frame at each call of Update() even if the state of the decoder is DecoderState.SEEK_FRAME.

Code (Based on ViveMediaDecoder.cs from the asset):

```
    //  Video progress is triggered using Update. Progress time would be set by nativeSetVideoTime.
    void Update() {
        Debug.Log(decoderState);
        switch (decoderState) {
            case DecoderState.START:
                if (isVideoEnabled) {
                    //  Prevent empty texture generate green screen.(default 0,0,0 in YUV which is green in RGB)
                    if (useDefault && nativeIsContentReady(decoderID)) {
                        getTextureFromNative();
                        setTextures(videoTexYch, videoTexUch, videoTexVch);
                        useDefault = false;
                    }

                    //  Update video frame by dspTime.
                    double setTime = AudioSettings.dspTime - globalStartTime;

                    //  Normal update frame.
                    if (setTime < videoTotalTime || videoTotalTime == -1.0f) {
                        if (seekPreview && nativeIsContentReady(decoderID)) {
                            setPause();
                            seekPreview = false;
                            unmute();
                        } else {
                            nativeSetVideoTime(decoderID, (float) setTime);
                            GL.IssuePluginEvent(GetRenderEventFunc(), decoderID);
                        }
                    } else {
                        isVideoReadyToReplay = true;
                    }
                }

                if (nativeIsVideoBufferEmpty(decoderID) && !nativeIsEOF(decoderID)) {
                    decoderState = DecoderState.BUFFERING;
                    hangTime = AudioSettings.dspTime - globalStartTime;
                }

                break;

            case DecoderState.SEEK_FRAME:

                    //
                    // Code Added:
                    //

                    setTime = AudioSettings.dspTime - globalStartTime;
                    nativeSetVideoTime(decoderID, (float) setTime);
                    GL.IssuePluginEvent(GetRenderEventFunc(), decoderID);

                    //
                    //

                if (nativeIsSeekOver(decoderID)) {
                    globalStartTime = AudioSettings.dspTime - hangTime;
                    decoderState = DecoderState.START;
                    if (lastState == DecoderState.PAUSE) {
                        seekPreview = true;
                        mute();
                    }
                }
                break;

            case DecoderState.BUFFERING:
                if (nativeIsVideoBufferFull(decoderID) || nativeIsEOF(decoderID)) {
                    decoderState = DecoderState.START;
                    globalStartTime = AudioSettings.dspTime - hangTime;
                }
                break;

            case DecoderState.PAUSE:
            case DecoderState.EOF:
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (isVideoEnabled || isAudioEnabled) {
            if ((!isVideoEnabled || isVideoReadyToReplay) && (!isAudioEnabled || isAllAudioChEnabled || isAudioReadyToReplay)) {
                decoderState = DecoderState.EOF;
                isVideoReadyToReplay = isAudioReadyToReplay = false;

                if (onVideoEnd != null) {
                    onVideoEnd.Invoke();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

- Result: Video pauses

I currently work around this problem by generating a reversed video beforehand and switch to the reversed videos whenever the user wants to rewind. However, given that our project use more then one 360 video and allows custom videos, the time needed to generate the reversed videos and the lag in switching the videos are unacceptably long.

Since the function is intuitively easy I think there must exist a much simpler solution. Have been stuck in this problem for a long time already so any pointers in solving the problem would be a big help!

Answer (score 0):

The videoPlayer in Unity is not very efficient and lags while rewinded, from my experience.

I found EasyMovieTexture asset to be better with Video rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be impossible until Unity team doesn't implement Video Source for their Video Player

You can try to use AVPro video player for this that's supports all main platforms. It is fastest video player now and they have support, so you can ask them if this is possible before buying assets.